# Can any one explain this code line in play framework?

Tags: playframework-1.x

```
User user = User.find("byName", name).).).first();
```

what is the use of `.first()` method.

Comment: Did you forget some code? There are 1 opening and 3 closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly because, when you request a name, there may be duplicates so it gives you a *list* of records (try to think of searching for a name like "John Smith").

The `.first()` would then give you the first record from that list.